# Remove content from a wordpress.com feed using yahoo pipes

Tags: regex, rss, yahoo-pipes

I am using yahoo pipes to get content matching a certian category from my WordPress.com Blog. Everything is working fine but WordPress adds "share" links to the bottom of the feed that I would like to remove.

Here is what's being added:

```
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://feeds.wordpress.com/1.0/gocomments/bandonrandon.wordpress.com/87/">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="http://feeds.wordpress.com/1.0/comments/bandonrandon.wordpress.com/87/"/></a>
    <img alt="" border="0" src="http://stats.wordpress.com/b.gif?host=bandonrandon.wordpress.com&blog=1046814&post=87&subd=bandonrandon&ref=&feed=1" width="1" height="1"/>
```

I edited out some of the services but you get the idea. I tried to use regex to remove this content what I tried was this:

```
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://feeds.wordpress.com/.*?><img alt="" border="0" src="http://feeds.wordpress.com.*?></a>
```

and

```
<img alt="" border="0" src="http://stats.wordpress.com.*?>
```

however it didn't fileter the results at all. 
Using this would filter ALL images and works fine

```
<a.*?><img.*?></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a[^>]+href="http://feeds.wordpress.com[^"]*"[^>]*>\s*<img[^>]+src="http://feeds.wordpress.com/[^"]*"[^>]*>\s*</a>\s*<img[^>]+src="http://stats.wordpress.com/[^"]*"[^>]*>
```

Regex updated, try that to match the whole lot.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's however still not working. If you want to play with the pipe feel free: http://pipes.yahoo.com/bandonrandon/wordpress_feed

Comment: The original regex worked in my test scenario, after a bit of learning of this pipes thing and a quick play around hopefully the above should work :)

Comment: It worked but I had to make it two request. I had to put stats on a seperate line from feeds. I forgot to mention there are like 10 services of feeds then the stat link. 

You're welcome to follow the link above to see the end result.